# rtmpdump - RTMP send error 32

Tags: linux, rtmp

I've problem with downloading video from rtmp stream. 
I'm trying to download stream from URL: http://stimotion.pl/galeria-kamer-online?catid=krosno&slg=dworzec 
In page source I found js file with player [http://stimotion.pl/flow/krosno/dworzec.js].
There is the info about stream - server: rtmp://80.48.180.7/krosno and name of stream: krosno2

I'm trying use rtmpdump to download it. I'm using this command:

```
rtmpdump -o str.flv -r rtmp://80.48.180.7/krosno -y krosno2
```

but i'm receiving a message:

```
RTMPDump v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
WARNING: HandShake: client signature does not match!
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: rtmp server sent error
Caught signal: 13, cleaning up, just a second...
ERROR: WriteN, RTMP send error 32 (42 bytes)
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
```

What should I do to save video from this stream ?
Is it possible?

Thank you for all replies

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question two years late, but I'm doing so simply because this error was driving me nuts. In my case, it didn't affect me directly, it was affecting my mother, living in another country, unable to listen to her favourite radio station.

I am pleased to say that I think the problem is solved upstream. It must have been one of the many buffer issues fixed upstream, and if you're running a new-ish version of your favourite distro, chances are it's fixed for you already.

If you're still on Ubuntu 14.04 though, here is a workaround. Get the new rtmpdump from git, and compile it statically, eg:

```
git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/rtmpdump
cd rtmpdump
```

Now edit the `Makefile` and where it says `LIB_RTMP=-Llibrtmp -lrtmp`, change it to:

```
LIB_RTMP=librtmp/librtmp.a
```

Now compile it:

```
make SYS=posix
```

The resulting binary will have librtmp1 statically linked, and will not interfere with the older librtmp0 on your system, so you avoid recompiling all those things too.

I can now listen to my favourite radio station uninterrupted, like so:

```
./rtmpdump --url rtmp://ingest1.netdynamix.fm/Magic828//Magic828.stream | vlc -
```